# Identify parts I need from a supplier catalog

Tags: automatic-transmission, volvo, repair, part-identification

I'm French and I own an old Volvo V70 car whose automatic gearbox sounds seriously tired.

In Europe an specially in France, automatic gearbox is not usual as it may be, say in USA, so it's not easy to find qualified service about it, and even less easy to buy involved spare parts (usually brand's representant propose only standard exchange, and it frequently costs more than the vehicle actual value!).

By chance I encountered a mechanic having real skills in this domain: he claims to perform the repair, and listed me which parts he needs for that. He also pointed me to its preferred supplier (Transtar), and I got its catalog, where I easily located the involved pages for my gearbox.

So I'm now trying to identify the parts he described, but here is the point: from the french description, looking at the catalog I'm not sure at all to look at the right part names in english. My (simply usual) English doesn't cover this particular domain, and Google translation doesn't seem to be reliable.

The mechanic said he needs:

- a complete set of *joints*: I guess it should be **seals** but the catalog includes **sealing rings**, **metal clad seals**, **axle seals**...
- a complete set of *plateaux* : I think of **plates** but I find **friction plates**, **steel plates** and **pressure plates**
- a complete set of *disques* : but I find no **disk** at all

Is there a chance that someone can identify which parts are so needed from [this catalog extract](http://www.screencast.com/t/JXILX9SX) (only 9 pages), knowing that my gearbox is AW 55-50 and my car is from 2001?

Comment: It appears you can get the rebuild kit. [See this](http://www.autozone.com/1/categories/volvo-v70-automatic-transmission-rebuild-kits). Something like that may be available in Europe/UK. It says the kit contains: **complete gasket set, friction set, sealing rings, and metal clad seals.** The friction set should make up the *plateaux* & *disques*, I would bet. You'd need the gasket set, obviously. The sealing rings and metal clad seals are obvious. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Paulster2. Thanks a lot for those informations: begins to become more clear, and this really helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you can get the rebuild kit. [See this](http://www.autozone.com/1/categories/volvo-v70-automatic-transmission-rebuild-kits). Something like that may be available in Europe/UK. It says the kit contains: complete gasket set, friction set, sealing rings, and metal clad seals. The friction set should make up the plateaux & disques, I would bet. You'd need the gasket set, obviously. The sealing rings and metal clad seals are obvious.